# Django DRF: @permission_classes not working

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a view with a custom action which should have a custom permission "IsRightUser". However, the `has_object_permission` of it is never called, even though I try to access the object with `self.get_object()` in my view.

```
class MyView(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    lookup_field = 'uuid'
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all()

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=True)
    @permission_classes([IsRightUser])
    def groups(self, request, uuid=None):
        # prints [<class 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'>]
        print(self.permission_classes)  
        my_object = self.get_object()
        groups = Group.objects.filter(my_object=my_object)
        serializer = MySerializer(groups, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here you can see my custom permission which is never called.

```
class IsRightUser(BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # never called
        return True
```

When I use `permission_classes = [IsRightUser]` in my view (i.e. directly underneath the lookup_field) **it works** (unfortunately this is not feasible for me).

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass permission classes as `action` argument directly:

```
@action(methods=['get'], detail=True, permission_classes=[IsRightUser])
def groups(self, request, uuid=None):
    # prints [<class 'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'>]
    print(self.permission_classes)  
    my_object = self.get_object()
    groups = Group.objects.filter(my_object=my_object)
    serializer = MySerializer(groups, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first decorator perfectly works as soon as you define a default DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES into settings.py under REST_FRAMEWORK for instance.